# How to report percentage of passed Test Scenarios in allure report instead of passed test steps

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

In our project using WebdriverIO we are currently generating allure report for % of test steps passed.
How can this be changed to generate % for test scenario passed instead?

For example: The feature file has scenarios as below:

```
Test Scenario 1:
Test Step 1
Test Step 2
...
Test Step 10

Test Scenario 2:
Test Step 1
Test Step 2
...
Test Step 10
```

If say all steps in Test Scenario1 execute successfully and Test Step6 onward fail in Test Scenario 2 the allure report states a passing of 75%. How can this be corrected to give result on Test Scenario basis?

Currently we have below in config file:

```
var isSteppassed = stepResult.getStatus();
if (isSteppassed != 'passed')
{
failed++}
```

Appreciate help

Answer (score 1):

Add line `useCucumberStepReporter: true` to `reporters: [['allure': {}]]`